# Nitrogen is not setting the wallpaper when i start i3

Tags: 13.10, i3-wm

Nitrogen is not starting on start of i3, i don't know why.

```
felipe@ubuntu:~$ cat .xinitrc 
 #!/usr/bin/env bash

exec i3
exec nitrogen --no-startup-id --restore
```

here is the config

```
felipe@ubuntu:~$ cat .config/nitrogen/bg-saved.cfg 
[:0.0]
file=/home/felipe/Imágenes/images-wallpaper-comics-87590.jpg
mode=4
bgcolor=#000000
```

here is the other

```
felipe@ubuntu:~$ cat .config/nitrogen/nitrogen.cfg 
[geometry]
posx=0
posy=18
sizex=1916
sizey=1041

[nitrogen]
view=icon
icon_caps=false
dirs=/home/felipe/Imágenes;
```

I start i3 from lightdm

Answer (score 3):

for i3 users

vim ~/.config/i3/config

then add the line below to your config

**exec --no-startup-id nitrogen --restore**

omitting *--restore* will cause the whole nitrogen app to come up instead of the wallpaper

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start nitrogen via xinitrc you would have to launch it before executing i3, so it would look something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
nitrogen &
exec i3
```

Or you could also use i3's config file to autostart nitrogen, just add the following somewhere into you i3 config.

```
...
exec --no-startup-id nitrogen
...
```